# Entity Framework: select property as Object

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm running into some trouble when trying to retrieve property values as Objects instead of their respective types. The following code throws this exception:

```
Unable to cast the type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.
```

This code works fine when selecting a string, but not when selecting DateTimes, Integers or Nullable types.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var ctx = new MyContext())
        {
            // Property selector: select DateTime as Object
            Expression<Func<Customer, object>> selector = cust => cust.CreatedOn;

            // Get set to query
            IQueryable<Customer> customers = ctx.Set<Customer>();

            // Apply selector to set. This throws: 
            // 'Unable to cast the type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.'
            IList<object> customerNames = customers.Select(selector).Distinct().ToList();

        }
    }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{

}
```

The end goal is a generic filtering to select distinct values from any of an object's properties.

Comment: You finally call `ToList`, so why not casting DateTime to object after that?

Comment: Because the selector member expression is created at runtime so the property type is not known at compile time. I could use reflection to determine the type, but that would be complicated for nested properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that you want to use the inline `Expression` declaration to select the property in a convenient way (without such as having to parse a dot-separated string representing the property path and using Reflection). However doing so will require the `Expression` to be declared explicitly and we have to use explicit type. Unfortunately that the `object` type cannot be used as the return type of the Expression because later on it cannot be converted to one of the supported types in the database.

I think there is a work-around here. The idea is we will convert the `Expression<T,object>` to another `Expression<T,returnType>` where `returnType` is the actual return type of the property (returned by `selector`). However `Select` always require an explicit type of `Expression<T,returnType>` meaning `returnType` should be known at design time. So that's impossible. We have no way to call `Select` directly. Instead we have to use Reflection to invoke the `Select`. The return result is expected as an `IEnumerable<object>` which you then can call `ToList()` to get a list of objects as what you want.

Now you can use this extension method for `IQueryable<T>`:

```
public static class QExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<object> Select<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, 
                                               Expression<Func<T, object>> exp) where T : class
    {
        var u = exp.Body as UnaryExpression;
        if(u == null) throw new ArgumentException("exp Body should be a UnaryExpression.");            
        //convert the Func<T,object> to Func<T, actualReturnType>
        var funcType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(source.ElementType, u.Operand.Type);
        //except the funcType, the new converted lambda expression 
        //is almost the same with the input lambda expression.
        var le = Expression.Lambda(funcType, u.Operand, exp.Parameters);            
        //try getting the Select method of the static class Queryable.
        var sl = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Select", 
                                 new[] { source.ElementType, u.Operand.Type }, 
                                 Expression.Constant(source), le).Method;
        //finally invoke the Select method and get the result 
        //in which each element type should be the return property type 
        //(returned by selector)
        return ((IEnumerable)sl.Invoke(null, new object[] { source, le })).Cast<object>();
    }        
}
```

**Usage**: (exactly as your code)

```
Expression<Func<Customer, object>> selector = cust => cust.CreatedOn;
IQueryable<Customer> customers = ctx.Set<Customer>();
IList<object> customerNames = customers.Select(selector).Distinct().ToList();
```

At first I tried accessing the `exp.Body.Type` and thought it was the actual return type of the inner expression. However somehow it's always `System.Object` except the special case of `string` (when the return type of property access is `string`). That means the info about the actual return type of the inner expression is totally lost (or at least hidden very carefully). That kind of design is fairly strange and totally unacceptable. I don't understand why they do so. The info about the actual return type of the expression should have been accessed easily.

Answer (score 0):

The point of linq to entity is creation of sql query with use of .NET linq instructions. The linq to entities instructions are not meant to be executed ever, they are only translated to sql. So everything inside those linq statements needs to be convertible to sql. And sql has proper types for date, string, etc. Classes are understood as tables where each property mean a certain column. But there is no concept of object in sql as it is in .NET and this is the source of your problem. In your linq query you should focus on creating only the query to return proper data and do the cast in your program:

```
Expression<Func<Customer, DateTime>> selector = cust => cust.CreatedOn;

// Get set to query
IQueryable<Customer> customers = ctx.Set<Customer>();

IList<object> customerNames = customers.Select(selector).Distinct().ToList().Cast<object>().ToList();
```

Every thing that you write in query up to first ToList is translated to sql query, the rest is executed in memory. So thanks to this we shift the cast part to memory where it makes sense to do it.

Comment: I'm working with user2346738 on this problem, we omitted some information for brevity's sake. The selector is created at runtime by creating a MemberExpression from a string (eg 'Country.Name' becomes customer => customer.Country.Name) so the property type is not known at compile time. We could use reflection to determine the type but that gets a bit nasty for nested members.